# SOQL always append the managed package namespace to the custom field (Custom field API name colision)

Tags: apex, soql, managed-package, isv, namespace

On my managed package, I have a custom field: `namespace__A__c`
The user also has a custom field `A__c`

If I do the following SOQL (dynamic or not)

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE A__c != NULL
```

it always appends the package namespace, and I cannot query the user's custom object.

How can I force an SOQL inside my managed package to not query the namespaced custom field?
How to do that in Apex directly?

**NOTES:**

- there's a comment [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/251681) from [@daniel-ballinger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/102/daniel-ballinger) saying that isn't possiblem but it's 4 years old, maybe there's a new trick.
- To do a DML operation, we can pass the Object schema, and it works.

Comment: The only apex-based workaround (i.e. avoiding using REST API) I'm aware of is to ensure that the SOQL query is executed in a class that is not part of the managed package. The package calls the unpackaged code (e.g. via Callable API) and receives back the results...

Comment: Depending on the field type,. the quick and dirty way is to create a formula field that points at the customer's field, and just query for that

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Wouldn't that have the same issue?

Comment: The issue is only if the field name is identical to one in the package -so if you create a formula field with a different api name, you don't get the collision

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC Actually, this is what I suggested to our client, and it worked. Not a pretty solution but at least he could run a SQOL with his custom field.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve both `A__c` and `NS__A__c` fields calling [Query REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm).
Keep in mind that to execute a SOQL via API you must always add the namespace to every field/object included in your managed package, so if in apex you have something like

```sql
SELECT Name, MyField__c FROM MyObject__c LIMIT 3
```

you should change it to

```sql
SELECT+Name,NS__MyField__c+FROM+NS__MyObject__c+LIMIT+3
```

The result will be a JSON like this:

```json
{
  "totalSize" : 3,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "NS__MyObject__c",
      "url" : "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/NS__MyObject__c/a0j8d000009DJ5YAAW"
    },
    "NS__MyField__c" : "0001",
    "Name" : "aaaa"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "NS__MyObject__c",
      "url" : "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/NS__MyObject__c/a0j8d000009DJ5OAAW"
    },
    "NS__MyField__c" : "0002",
    "Name" : "bbbb"
  }, {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "NS__MyObject__c",
      "url" : "/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/NS__MyObject__c/a0j8d000009DJ5AAAW"
    },
    "NS__MyField__c" : "0003",
    "Name" : "cccc"
  } ]
}
```

You could deserialize the `records` property into a list of SObject, i.e.:

```
List<MyObject__c> aList = (List<MyObject__c>) JSON.deserialize(result.records, List<MyObject__c>.class);
```

If you need more than 2000 records it may not be worth it, since you have to execute multiple API calls.

Please also note that a security review may fail if you use `UserInfo.getSessionId()`, you could read more about it [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/389121/62544).

Comment: In 2023, there was definitely a change in the security review policies and using the REST API will fail the security review.

Comment: @SamuelCarreira The security review will fail only if you use `UserInfo.getSessionId()`. Using REST/Tooling/Metadata API is fine, I added a link in the answer, several users of SFSE passed the security review and added their solutions to [that post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/389121/)

Comment: When I had to implement a system to access the tooling API I ended up creating an open-source package so the client could install it without issues. It uses the trick to get `UserSessionId` from the VisualForce page context.
Because the "connected app methods" aren't the best experience for an AppExchange easy to use app.